# react native navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition not updating

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I am using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` to get current location in mobile app.

At first it's getting current location correctly.

I am calling the function every second to keep location values(latitude, longitude) updated.

But each time I call the function it's returning same values and the `timestamp` is not changing as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the parameter 'maximumAge' and set it to 0 to avoid getting cached values. e.g.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      region: {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude
      }
}, err => {
  console.log(err)
  alert('fetching the position failed')
}, {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 0})
```

As per [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions/maximumAge) :

> The PositionOptions.maximumAge property is a positive long value indicating the maximum age in milliseconds of a possible cached position that is acceptable to return. If set to 0, it means that the device cannot use a cached position and must attempt to retrieve the real current position. If set to Infinity the device must return a cached position regardless of its age.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass additional options to `getCurrentPosition()` .
Supported options are `timeout (ms), maximumAge (ms), enableHighAccuracy (bool)`.
Here you can see the maximumAge option. It will return the cached location data if there is a cached location within the maximumAge limit. You can set it to 0, so it will not return any cached data, instead read and return location data everytime you make a location request.

Also I am not sure if you will get updated location every second, it is an async task and sometimes longer than one second to complete the whole `request > read location > send back response` process. You'll have to keep this in mind too.

Answer (score 0):

On my environment, value 0 was treated as `infinity` . (I am using react-native)

So, I needed to change from `maximumAge: 0` to `maximumAge: 1`.

Then I could get correct current position every time.